# Accessing mails from "mail\ServerMailFile.nsf" file from Domino Server using "Interop.Domino.dll"

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, interop-domino

I can open contacts,to-do list from "mail/usermail.nsf" file.
But unable to open or access mails from it.

I am using below code to access "calender":

```
_serverDatabase = _lotesNotesSession.GetDatabase("", "mail\ServerMailFile.nsf", false);
 NotesView LotusNotesView = _localDatabase.GetView("Calendar");
```

Is there any similar way to access mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead NotesView LotusNotesView = _localDatabase.GetView("($Inbox)");

The Calendar view only gets calendar docs (meetings, reminders, appointments, etc).